# How to remove/exclude a commit from a fork?

Tags: git, github

Alright, so think of this scenario:

I forked a GitHub repo and pushed a commit. I made a pull request to the original repo containing just that commit as it was the fork's only commit by me. The pull request was rejected and closed by the original author. I now know that that commit will never be pushed to the original repo, but I have a new commit that I want to push to the original repo. So, I push the commit to the fork and go to submit a pull request, when I see that both the new and older commit are to be added to the pull request, and there is no option to choose which commits to add.

How can I remove/exclude a commit from a fork/pull request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a fresh copy of the upstream, and make your modifications on top of that. It looks like you messed up your repository and don't know how to untangle the mess, so it will probably be better so move what you have to a save place and clone afresh. In the clone, create a branch off the tip for your work, i.e., `git checkout -b my-work`. Do work in the `my-work` branch (by cribing differences from your messed up repo, probably). When you are satisfied with that, push the result upstream. Don't work on the `master` branch, keep that one for the original version.